# How to plot group delay and phase delay for a continuous time transfer function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, delay, continuous, phase

I have created a continuous time transfer function (s-domain) with the "tf" command. Now I can use the command "bodeplot" to plot magnitude and phase characteristics.

Now I would like to plot group delay and phase delay as well (both as a function of frequency). I stumbled upon the commands "grpdelay" and "phasedelay" but they seem to work with discrete time filters only. What are the continuous time equivalents?

I have searched all over the internet with no luck so far :-(

Comment: Is there really not straight forward method meaning any predefined script which can be used?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a straight forward function to do this. You're probably better off by extracting the phase information for many points and then finding the derivative (multiplied by -1),